# Cycles render light pixels remove

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

This is a crop of my render test with cycles.

[image]

My Workstation: Win10, GPU Compute with NVIDIA 1050Ti
How can remove all the light pixels in the scene?

Render settings

[image: Render Settings]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set you *Samples* (of the render option) up very high (minimum of 300) to get of "Fireflies" (the name given to these pixels). **Note**: This will increase render times quite a bit.

[image]

Comment: I try to set this parameter at 750  but the Fireflies still again, also in my settings i check the options "Squares Samples" so the total samples become 576 with AA you can see in sampling panels.

Comment: but are there less

Comment: No 750 is enough, the problem is related to the size lights and corresponding shadows size. Also is related to clamp indirect parameter.

The blender guru tutorials explan very well how to solve the fireflies problems.

https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies/

Answer (score 0):

Increase the *Clamp Indirect* value. Try start with 1.
You can find it under *Sampling* > *Settings*.